# How can save the exact code to text file. like %date%

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

use this way to create text file, but execute some code in result

this code want to save:

```
>> sina2.txt echo SET TodayYear=^%DATE:~10,4^%
>> sina2.txt echo SET TodayMonth=%DATE:~4,2%
>> sina2.txt echo SET TodayDay=%DATE:~7,2%
>> sina2.txt echo IF %MyDate% GTR %TodayYear%-%TodayMonth%-%TodayDay% (
>> sina2.txt echo ECHO MyDate is Bigger Do Nothing.
```

result is not same as code. "I want exactly the letter, one by one"

```
SET TodayYear=2022
SET TodayMonth=02
SET TodayDay=03
IF  GTR -- (
ECHO MyDate is Bigger Do Nothing.
```

want result like this:

```
SET TodayYear=%DATE:~10,4%
SET TodayMonth=%DATE:~4,2%
SET TodayDay=%DATE:~7,2%
IF %MyDate% GTR %TodayYear%-%TodayMonth%-%TodayDay% (
ECHO MyDate is Bigger Do Nothing.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd generally double the percent characters, a little like this:

```sh
1>"sina2.txt" (
    Echo Set "Today=%%DATE%%"
    Echo Set "TodayYear=%%Today:~-4%%"
    Echo Set "TodayMonth=%%Today:~-10,2%%"
    Echo Set "TodayDay=%%Today:~-7,2%%"
    Echo If %%MyDate%% GTR %%TodayYear%%-%%TodayMonth%%-%%TodayDay%% (
    Echo    ECHO MyDate is Bigger Do Nothing.
    Echo ^)
)
```

*You should note, that as I've parenthesized the entire block, internal closing parentheses require escaping with a caret. Also I have used the dynamic variable `%DATE%` just once, then used its static value as the basis for the others, (this prevents issues with date rollovers). It should also be noted that you have not defined `%MyDate%` so the content you are writing is incomplete.*

Answer (score 1):

Precede the lines you want to write out with `::::`<sup>1</sup>, then use [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to filter them out from the batch file, [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to capture the resulting lines and [sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)<sup>2</sup> to remove the prefix `::::`:

```cmd
@echo off
> "%~dp0sina2.txt" (
    for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%B in ('findstr "^::::" "%~f0"') do (
        set "LINE=%%B"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!LINE:*::::=!
        endlocal
    )
)
exit /B

::::SET TodayYear=%DATE:~10,4%
::::SET TodayMonth=%DATE:~4,2%
::::SET TodayDay=%DATE:~7,2%
::::IF %MyDate% GTR %TodayYear%-%TodayMonth%-%TodayDay% (
::::ECHO MyDate is Bigger Do Nothing.
```

With this method, the target lines never pass through the command interpreter, hence no variable expansion or special character recognition occurs.

[Delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is toggled within the loop in order not run into issues with exclamation marks.

---

<sub>1)  The prefix `::::` has been chosen since `:` introduces a jump label (see [`goto`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)), `::` marks an invalid label often used as a [comment](https://ss64.com/nt/rem.html), perhaps also withing thithe current script, and `::::` is still an invalid comment though unusual and rarely (or hopefully never) used.</sub>

<sub>2)  Sub-string substitution in the loop and the corresponding need of delayed expansion could be avoided when using `for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('findstr "^::::" "%~f0"') do echo(%%B`, but this would dismiss *all* leading colons.</sub>